# Bootstrap 4 col sorting mobile vs desktop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to archieve the following order of cols on mobile:
[image]
  And order of cols on desktop:
[image]

with this HTML:

```
    <div class="row portitems">

        <div class="col-4 col-md-3 portcol">
            <img src="images/portfolio/thumb_1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Titel" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-4 col-md-3 portcol">
            <img src="images/portfolio/thumb_2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Titel" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-4 col-md-3 portcol">
            <img src="images/portfolio/thumb_3.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Titel" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-4 col-md-3 portcol">
            <img src="images/portfolio/thumb_4.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Titel" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-4 col-md-3 portcol">
            <img src="images/portfolio/thumb_4.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Titel" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-4 col-md-3 portcol">
            <img src="images/portfolio/thumb_4.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Titel" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 portcol promocol col-md-pull-2">
            <div class="innerpromo">
                <h2>Need an experienced stylist?</h2>
                <a href="#" class="mybtn white"><svg><use xlink:href="#icon-chevron-right" /></svg> Contact me</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4 col-md-3 portcol">
            <img src="images/portfolio/thumb_1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Titel" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-4 col-md-3 portcol">
            <img src="images/portfolio/thumb_2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Titel" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-4 col-md-3 portcol">
            <img src="images/portfolio/thumb_3.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Titel" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-4 col-md-3 portcol">
            <img src="images/portfolio/thumb_4.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Titel" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-4 col-md-3 portcol">
            <img src="images/portfolio/thumb_4.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Titel" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-4 col-md-3 portcol">
            <img src="images/portfolio/thumb_4.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Titel" />
        </div>

    </div>
```

Mobile shows just fine but on desktop I get
4 cols,
2 cols,
1 full width col,
4 cols

Does anyone have an idea how to get the proper sorting on desktop?

Comment: Do you want 3 or 4 columns on Desktop?

Comment: 4 columns on Desktop